# Producing Answer in Columns with different "for" loops

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, multiple-columns

My assignment is to print a list of the even numbers, odd numbers, and ALL numbers in 3 columns. I've managed to get the even column and odd column to work, but not the ALL column to work. I know it's because the ALL column is in a different for loop but I'm not sure how to solve this since it needs to be in a different "for" loop to count by 1 and not by 2 like in the odd and even one.
[Click for Sample Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1AEW.png).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
void no_10_add_even_odd_all_from_min_to_max(int min, int max);
int main()
{
    int min;
    int max;
    int first;
    int second; 

    cout<<"Enter first number:";
    cin>>first;
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"Enter second number:";
    cin>>second;
    cout<<endl;

    if (first>second){
        max = first;
        min = second;}
    else{
        max = second;
        min = first;}

    no_10_add_even_odd_all_from_min_to_max(min,max);
    return 0;
}

void no_10_add_even_odd_all_from_min_to_max(int min, int max){
    cout<<"10. Add the even , the odd, and ALL numbers";
    cout<<endl;
    const int SPACING =5;

    for(int n = min; n <= max; n+=2)
        cout<<setw(SPACING)<<n
            <<setw(SPACING)<<n+1<<endl;
    for(int n = min; n<=max; n++)
        cout<<setw(SPACING)<<n<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Recommend adding a sample of the output you are getting and the output you would like to get in order to remove ambiguity for the answerers.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to convert even and odd numbers to string, so that when you have printed them all and still have ALL numbers to print, you can just print nothing:

```
void no_10_add_even_odd_all_from_min_to_max(int min, int max)
{
    cout << "10. Add the even, the odd, and ALL numbers" << endl;
    const int SPACING = 10;

    int even = min, odd = min;
    if (min % 2 == 0)
        ++odd;
    else
        ++even;

    for (int all = min; all <= max; ++all, even += 2, odd += 2) cout
        << setw(SPACING) << (even <= max ? to_string(even) : "") 
        << setw(SPACING) << (odd <= max ? to_string(odd) : "")
        << setw(SPACING) << all 
        << endl;
}
```